# Changing date time format in all rows in csv file

Tags: python, csv, datetime

I have a csv file with data in this form..

```
2018-06-01T09:20:00+0530,16.85,16.9,16.85,16.9,1000
2018-06-01T09:21:00+0530,16.9,17,16.9,17,500
2018-06-01T09:22:00+0530,17,17,15.5,15.5,500
2018-06-01T09:23:00+0530,15.5,15.5,15.5,15.5,0
```

And I need to get it into this format..

```
01/06/2018 09:20:00,16.85,16.9,16.85,16.9,1000
01/06/2018 09:21:00,16.9,17,16.9,17,500
01/06/2018 09:22:00,17,17,15.5,15.5,500
01/06/2018 09:23:00,15.5,15.5,15.5,15.5,0
```

Basically the date format has to be changed for all rows in the file.. I have not been able to code this and using macros is rather painful.

Comment: How does your current Python source code look like?

Comment: I had this which works for most parts..import os
import csv
import dateutil.parser
from datetime import datetime,tzinfo,timedelta
f = open('f:\Downloads\Sample.csv')
csv_f = csv.reader(f)
csv_f.next() # skip header line
for row in csv_f:
 dt = datetime.strptime(row[0], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+0530')
 with open("f:\Downloads\Temp.csv",'w') as f1:
  csv_w = csv.writer(f1)
         csv_w.writerow([dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5])

Comment: Oops, Id posted a comment, has vanished.. Managed the date parsing and reformatting.. but was couldnt get the data back into the new file.. The code I had at last was like....import csv
import dateutil.parser
from datetime import datetime,tzinfo,timedelta
with open("f:\Downloads\Sample.csv",'r') as f:
    with open("f:\Downloads\Temp.csv",'w') as f1:
       f.next() # skip header line
       for row in f:
  dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(row[0], '%y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+0530')  # parsing the datetime
              f1.writerow(dt '%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S', row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final code which works on python version 2.7.15, which is drawn from that posted by [Martin Evans](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4985733/martin-evans) is as follows:

```
from datetime import datetime
import csv

with open('f:\Downloads\Sample.csv') as f_input, open('f:\Downloads\Temp.csv', 'w') as f_output:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    csv_input.next()                            # skip header line
    for row in csv_input:
        dt = datetime.strptime(row[0], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+0530')    #parse the datetime
        row[0] = dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')           #assign the revised format
        csv_output.writerow(row)
```

Thanx everyone..

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using Python's CSV and datetime libraries as follows:

```
from datetime import datetime
import csv

with open('input.csv', 'rb') as f_input, open('output.csv', 'wb') as f_output:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)

    for row in csv_input:
        dt = datetime.strptime(row[0], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')
        row[0] = dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
        csv_output.writerow(row)
```

This would create an `output.csv` file containing:

```
01/06/2018 09:20:00,16.85,16.9,16.85,16.9,1000
01/06/2018 09:21:00,16.9,17,16.9,17,500
01/06/2018 09:22:00,17,17,15.5,15.5,500
01/06/2018 09:23:00,15.5,15.5,15.5,15.5,0
```

`strptime()` is used to convert your existing date into a Python `datetime` object. This can then be converted back into the format you need using the `strftime()` function. These use a special format to identify parts of the date using a [format specification](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/datetime.html?highlight=strptime#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

The csv library is used to read a line of the file in and automatically split it into a row containing a list of strings. `row[0]` holds the first value.

Comment: Thanx, It worked; with some modifications.. The newline part was not being accepted.. and also this needed change.. dt = datetime.strptime(row[0], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+0530').. Not sure why though.. it was not accepting %z. Thanx a ton

Comment: `newline=''` is needed for Python 3.x (which is assumed unless you say otherwise). For Python 2.x you need to use `wb`, I will update it.

Comment: If you're on Python 3.7+, you can use `datetime.datetime.fromisoformat` to parse. If not, `dateutil.parser.parse` is another option to deal with ISO8601 parsing.